# Can all the function of a matrix be diagonalized in the same form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $A$ admit a diagonalization, that is $A = S\Lambda S^{-1}$ for some matrices $S$ and $\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal.

I know that $e^A$ can also be diagonalized. Indeed, by Taylor expansion 
$$
e^{A}=Se^{\Lambda}S^{-1}.
$$

However, I am confused if the function is not in the domain of convergence of Taylor expansion. For example, if we consider $A \mapsto \frac{1}{e^{A}-1}$, can I also get the diagonalization of the form
$$
\frac{1}{e^{A}-1} = S\frac{1}{e^{\Lambda}-1}S^{-1} ? 
$$

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat I mean can my second expression diagonalized by the methods of the first expression

Comment: Wait, I don't even know which you are referring to, what's $e^\wedge$?

Comment: @JohnMa That is the diagonal matrix of $A$ : $A = S\wedge S^{-1}$

Comment: I edited your question, hope that reflects what you are asking. @J.X.Zhang

Comment: But I think that $\frac{1}{e^{z}-1}$ is not analytic at the $ z = 0$.  If so,  $f(z)=\sum_{n}c_{n}z^{n}$,where n should involve negative number. Can I still write it as $P^{-1}f(A)P$? @reuns

Comment: If $P^{-1} A P$ is diagonal then so is $P^{-1} A^n P$ and hence $P^{-1} f(A)P$ for any polynomial or analytic function. $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ is analytic and hence given by a Laurent series on some annuli. Otherwise you can define $P^{-1} f(A) P$ directly from the eigenvalues. In general to define $f(A)$ if $A$ is not diagonalisable and outside a disk or annulus of convergence, you'll need some functional calculus $f(A) = \frac{1}{2i \pi } \int_C f(z) (zI-A)^{-1}dz$

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you! @reuns

Answer (score 0):

If the question is: "for any power series $F$ in $X$ that leads to a converging series after substitution of any eigenvalue of$~A$, in order that we can define the substitution $F[X:=\Lambda]$ by simply substituting the diagonal entries into$~S$, does it hold that $F[X:=A]$ converges and is equal to $SF[X:=\Lambda]S^{-1}$?", then the answer is "yes", since such substitution commutes with change of basis.